# Unable to set MouseListeners at Parent level in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouselistener

I have a `JPanel` named `parent` and then have another `JPanel` named `child`.

I added:

```
parent.addMouseListener(new MouseInputListener(){
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent ev){
     System.out.println("Pressed")
   }
});
parent.add(child);
```

Now whenever I tap on child panel, the parent event is not getting triggered. If I tap on other areas of parent, event is getting triggered.

I don't want to add event listener at child level as I will be adding many children for which I don't repeat this coding.

Is there a way in which I can set `MouseListener` at parent level so that all child can respond to it?

Comment: *"- JDK 1.4"*  Wait, ..what?  That version was obsoleted years ago!

Comment: BTW - why is the user clicking on panels rather than a button or buttons or menu items, etc.?

Comment: 1. Is there a way in which I can set MouseListener at parent level so that all child can respond to it? !=  for which I don't repeat this coding., because childs are in ontop in components hierarchy, then to consume all mouse and key events, you have to dispatch all those event back to the container ( !=  for which I don't repeat this coding.), and thats logics, users friendly, expected reaction and valid for majority of todays programing languages and thier GUI

Comment: Andrew, For your comment 1, I got a legacy code to modify :( For your comment 2, I am basically trying to react to flick event, to make things simplify I just added code for mouse pressed

Comment: Tip: Add @mKorbel (or whoever, **the `@` is important**) to notify the person of a new comment.